# Updating database after updating resultset

Tags: java, jdbc

I have the below code to get data from a database and update it. How ever, result set is getting updated but, I don't see the changes in the database. Even after I say commit(), database is not getting updated. What am I missing here?

```
  Connection connect = ConnectionManager.getInstance().getConnection();
            Statement st = connect.createStatement();

            st.execute("Select * from ...");
            ResultSet rs = st.getResultSet();
            ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData() ;
            rs.absolute(1);
            rs.updateObject("StepName","ABCD" ); 

            connect.commit();
            //connect.close();
```

EDIT:

Now, i have the below method, but I get the error as indicated.

```
            rs.updateString("StepName", "ABCD");
            rs.updateRow();
            //rs.updateObject("StepName","ABCD" );
```

Error: com.jnetdirect.jsql.u: sp_cursor: The cursor identifier value provided (0) is not valid.

OK I have it working now. Below is the way I had to change.
Working solution:

```
Connection connect = ConnectionManager.getInstance().getConnection();
             Statement st = connect.createStatement(
                        ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
                        ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

            st.execute("Select * from ...");
            ResultSet rs = st.getResultSet();
            String queuename = "apples";    
            String updatedname = "bananas";

            while(rs.next())
            {

                if(rs.getString(3).equals(queuename))
                {   
                rs.updateString(3, updatedname );
                System.out.println("updated: " + rs.getString(3));
                rs.updateRow();
                }else
                {
                    System.out.println(rs.getRow() + ": " +  rs.getString(3));
                }
            }

            connect.commit();
            rs.close();
            connect.close();

        }
```

Comment: Your ResultSet doesn't support updatable cursors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the spec of `updateObject` :

> Updates the designated column with an Object value. The updater methods are used to update column values in the current row or the insert row. **The updater methods do not update the underlying database**; instead **the updateRow or insertRow methods are called to update the database**.

`rs.updateObject` alone doesn't update the database. Try adding a call to `rs.updateRow()` after `updateObject`.

Comment: @user2945142 Is it possible your ResultSet is empty?

Comment: No. When I do System.out.print(rs.getString(3)); I get the value of third column. So  my resultset is not empty.

Answer (score 1):

rs.absolute(1); might be not be moving the cursor. Try:
    rs.next();

You can try a straight up SQL statement:

```
StringBuffer updates = new StringBuffer();
updates.append("UPDATE table_name ");
updates.append("SET StepName = ? );
updates.append("WHERE id = ?");

Statement updateStatement = connect.createStatement(updates.toString());
updateStatement.setString(1, "BlaBla");
updateStatement.setInt(2, 143);

updateStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Hmm... did you try rs.updateObject(3,"ABCD"); ? maybe there is no StepName column label...

Comment: Yes. Tried that as well.

Answer (score 1):

When you make your call to createStatement you need to use the overload that allows you to specify an updatable resultset.

[Here is an example if found:  http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/how-to-use-updatable-resultset-in-jdbc/179](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/how-to-use-updatable-resultset-in-jdbc/179)

I think it's possible that not all driver\databases support this operation.